# Convert MemoryStream to byte[]- Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream

I hav a file upload can upload file as async

```
   $("#files").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: "AddFile",              
              autoUpload: true
          }
    });
```

And in AddFile action I Store posted file in a tempData

```
   public ActionResult AddFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        TempData["PostedFile"] = files;
        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

In Create Action when I want that convert postedfile Inputdtream to byte[] I have an exception

> Cannot access a closed file

```
  if ((TempData["PostedFile"] as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>)!= null)
     {

      var postedfile =(TempData["PostedFile"] as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>).ElementAt(0);

       MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
       postedfile.InputStream.CopyTo(target);//This Line Has exception
       byte[] data = target.ToArray();
      }
```

**Update**
When I upolad a file thas its size is 80Kb my code worked  ...when my file sizze is 500k mycode has exception!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That is correct behavior of MVC engine. Why not to store byte array in TempData in AddFile action?